# list containing the second elements of the list members in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to do solve a old midterm problem from a previous year and I having a lot of trouble with this one.

Using list comprehension, implement a function with the following type:

```
collectSecond :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

such that (collectSecond xs) returns a list containing the second elements of the list members of xs, except for those list members with a length less than two. For example:

```
collectSecond [[1,2,3], [4], [], [5,6]] ~> [2,6]
collectSecond [[1], [], [2]] ~> []
collectSecond [] ~> []
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pattern matching in the list comprehension to get out the second element like so:

```
collectSecond xs = [x2 |  x1:x2:rest <-  xs]
```

Here x2 matches to the second element of each of lists that xs contains, if any.

```
Prelude> collectSecond [[1,2,3], [4], [], [5,6]]
[2,6]
```

And if there is no second element, then no element is added to the list for that sub list.  See the [4] and [] in above example for instance.

Comment: Thanks so much! Lists within lists were confusing me so much.

Answer (score 1):

It's also pretty simple to implement using basic recursion:

```
collectSecond ((x0:x1:_):ys) = x1:(collectSecond ys)
collectSecond (_:ys)         = collectSecond ys
collectSecond []             = []
```

(Here we handle each element individually, and add its seconds element to the list we're creating if there is one, and skip it if it has no second element)

You could also use [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aconcatMap):

```
collectSecond xs = concatMap seconds xs
    where seconds (x0:x1:_) = [x1]
          seconds _         = []
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful seeing this from another perspective.